# A good tutorial for Visual Studio c++ linker

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

I've started working on solutions with LOTS of different c++ projects.

I want to understand better the different types of libraries (static/dynamic libraries).
MFC static/shared...
using ATL...

And basically understanding the meaning of the 100s of options in a c++ project properties.

Can anyone recommend a good source (Book or site) where I can read about it ? (Hopefully something to the point, and not 10000s of pages)

Comment: You need to understand the basic problems that linkers solve first - take a look at http://www.iecc.com/linker.

Comment: I second Neil's recommendation. Project properties encompass more than just the linker. It'll get clearer as you learn what it's doing better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa315045%28VS.60%29.aspx) and [linker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa270751%28VS.60%29.aspx) reference from MSDN. And another link that might be worth looking at is: [Creating and Managing Visual C++ Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4457htyc.aspx)

Apart from the Microsoft solutions, you can also take a look at [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/runningcmake.html). Here is the [CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/documentation.html) with links to wiki, tutorial and reference.

Comment: @Neil-Butterworth: I made the CMake suggestion just as an alternative to MS tools since the OP was talking about managing multiple Visual Studio projects.